# Add file to repository without clone or download all file in repo

Tags: git

I have a remote git repository at this address: `https://github.com/user/repo.git`

I want add 100 files on my local computer to this repository, without cloning  the remote repository.

How can I do that?

---

For example, I create 100 files:

```
touch {1..100}
```

and I want to add these local files to the remote repository without cloning the remote repository.

Is this possible and if so, how can I accomplish it?

Comment: make a shallow clone. I don't think you can commit without having the parent commit available.

Comment: You may be able to use the [GitHub API](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/#create-a-file) to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Now github supports adding files using the web interface. Just click on the upload button, chose your files and upload it. You can select multiple files.

[image]